# No sound after installing nVidia drivers in Xubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio

Sound stopped working on a display port connected monitor after installing nVidia drivers for a `gtx 660`.

I tried restarting pulseaudio and switching between each of output devices however no sound was coming through the display port.

Searching through the forums I found some diagnostic scripts however none of them resulted in sound coming out of the speakers.

```
>>> aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>>> aplay -D hw:1,3 testsound.wav
aplay: main:788: audio open error: Device or resource busy
>>> aplay -D hw:1,7 testsound.wav
Playing WAVE 'testsound.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
>>> aplay -D hw:1,8 testsound.wav
Playing WAVE 'testsound.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
>>> aplay -D hw:1,9 testsound.wav
Playing WAVE 'testsound.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
```

How to get sound working on my computer again?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a known bug in the recent driver versions. See: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1019761/linux/no-sound-using-displayport-audio-with-375-82-384-59-and-384-69/

Looks like we have to either wait for an update or downgrade to an older version.